# sameperiodlastyear returns a blank/null value

Tags: powerbi, dax

This clip works properly and returns the sum of all entries from the beginning of this FY to the end of last month.

```
FY22 Reimburse Total = 
var SetOfDates=DATESBETWEEN('Calendar'[Date],[FirstDayFY],[FirstDayThisMonth])
return
CALCULATE(SUM(FY22_All[Dollars]),SetOfDates
)
```

I want to compare the same time period last year, and used this measure, but this one returns (Blank)

```
FY21 Reimburse Total = var SetOfDates=SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DATESBETWEEN('Calendar'[Date],[FirstDayFY],[FirstDayThisMonth]))
return
CALCULATE(SUM(FY22_All[Dollars]),SetOfDates
)
```

Comment: Add, please, a code for  dates in datesbetween.

Comment: FirstDayFY - is it a measure or var? Please, add your code for it, and for other date.

Comment: FirstDayFY is a measure. 

 FirstDayFY = CALCULATE(
    var YearFY = if(month(today())>9,(year(today())+1),(YEAR(today())))  
    var FirstDayFY=DATE((YearFY-1),10,1)
   return
   FirstDayFY
   )

Comment: FirstDayThisMonth = CALCULATE(
DATE(year(today()),month(today()),1)
)

Comment: YearFY-1, for the first day in var FirstDayFY, you double deduct for this year in a measure and in sameperiod

Comment: How do you create calendar?

Comment: What is a current FY?

Comment: Try STARTOFYEAR() for the first date. You can adjust it for your FY. I’m on trip, sorry for spam). Pretty sure that the problem is in a setOfDays - FirstDay. You can check it with max and min dates.

Comment: I'll try that.  I've tried every other combination I can think of.  I often get errors calling the FirstDayFY measure a true/false expression, so it may be a format issue.

Comment: Ok, please, let me know about startofyear attempt )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a separate fact table for each FY like `FY22_All`, you never get `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR` for it. This expression:

```
SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(
    DATESBETWEEN('Calendar'[Date],[FirstDayFY],[FirstDayThisMonth])
)
```

returns `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR` for the `'Calendar'[Date]` table, but it can be, that returned period doesn't exist in the `FY22_All` . So, when you filter the `FY22_All` table with `SetOfDates` you receive an empty table.  Try to alter your expression like this:

```
FY21 Reimburse Total = 
VAR SetOfDates=
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(
            DATESBETWEEN('Calendar'[Date],[FirstDayFY],[FirstDayThisMonth])
        )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(FY21_All[Dollars]) -- FY22_All -> FY21_All 
        ,SetOfDates
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Original code worked, but was missing pertinent data in the fact table.  Once data was entered, both original snippets returned the desired value.

Comment: Was my answer correct, then?